# Logging to remote server without specifying username

Tags: ssh

Today I configured ssh keys access to my server. Then I tested them and by mistake I forgot to specify the user, so instead of doing it like that:

```
ssh username@myserver.com
```

I did it like that

```
ssh myserver.combut
```

I successfully logged in as username. How is that possible? How does ssh server know under which user to log me in? If it's a key, than it's possible that I'll have the same key added to multiple users, what's going to happen in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If same user you have in your system from which you want to login then no need to use `username` for login it will take default system user.
for example : your one system(client) have user `test` and your ssh server also have user `test` then no need to mention username like :

```
ssh username@myserver.com
```

you can use like:

```
ssh myserver.com
ssh serverip
```

make sure when you doing ssh you have login as that user in your client system. 
yes, you can do for multiple users like your client system have user `user1` , `user2` , `user3` etc. then you have to create that user in your ssh server also . then if you want to login then do like :

```
su - user1 
ssh sshserverip
```

you will login as `user1`. if you do

```
su - user2
ssh sshserverip
```

you will login as `user2`.
If you want login as another user then you have to put username otherwise system will confuse which user have to login.

```
ssh username@serverip
```

or

```
ssh serverip -l username
```

or

if you want to do key based authentication then you have to add public key of all users in `authorized_keys` . for more info visit [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)

Comment: thanks, so what's going to happen if my user differs from that on remote and I have my public key uploaded to remote but I don't specify username when trying to connect through ssh?

Comment: still you have to mention username .

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mention the username, `ssh` will use the username you are currently logged in as.

So:

```
username@client$ ssh username@myserver.com
```

is analogous to:

```
username@client$ ssh myserver.com
```

All the other parameters like keys, passwords will be used in the usual manner.